# What inheritance for my Object class to weapon class & armor class

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm making a little game with a hero having inventory filled with object.

```
public enum Objects_type 
{
    WEAPON,
    ARMOR
}

public abstract class Objects_class 
{
    protected String name;
    protected Objects_type type;

    public Objects_class(String name, Objects_type type) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public abstract class Armor extends Objects_class{

    int life = 0;
    int res_fire = 0;

    public Armor(String name, int largeur, int hauteur) {
        super(name, Objects_type.ARMOR);
    }
}

public abstract class Weapon extends Objects_class 
{
    protected int dmg_fire = 0;

    public Weapon(String name) {
        super(name, Objects_type.WEAPON);
    }
}

public class StickOfJoy extends Weapon{

    public StickOfJoy() {
        super("Stick of Joy");
        dmg_fire = 2;
    }
}

public class ArmorOfPity extends Armor{ 
    public ArmorOfPity() 
    {
        super("Armor of Pity");
        life = 30;
    }
}
```

Then I have functions like :

```
Hero.getObject (Objects_class obj)
{
   if (obj.getType == Objects_type.WEAPON)
   ....
}
```

I'd like to be able to consider the Objects_class obj as a Weapon but of course it's not possible (casting a mother to its child) so it makes me think my inheritance structure is bad.

What should I've done ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language and/or framework you're using. Don't make us infer by the syntax.

Comment: My suggestion depends on what you are doing inside the if(obj.getType==...).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart done, sorry for this.

Comment: @arynaq Makin something like Weapon left_hand = obj

Comment: Get rid of Objects_type, use instanceof, and down-cast.

Comment: @DavidConrad could you be more clear please ? (write an answer ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Conrad has some good points I recommend you read through that I won't repeat here but here is how I would do it.

Suppose you have a character that is roaming around in your game world picking up items, there can be many different items, some so different from each other in behavior they warrant the creation of a new subclass (like picking up boots vs picking up wings).

Once you pick up an item, you have the choice of letting the hero try and see what kind of item was picked up (instanceof, enums, whatever) or you can let the item figure out where it is supposed to go.

Here is a simplified example where the player has only two inventory slots, a weapon and an armor. Notice how easy it is to simply add a new item (like a health potion, or a superdupernewspecialweapon) to the mix without having to change anything in the player or do casting.

```
public abstract class Item {
    private int ID;
    private static int IDCounter;
    private String name;

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = IDCounter;
        IDCounter++;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public abstract void attachToPlayer(Player player);
}

public class Armor extends Item {
    private int life;
    private int res_fire;

    public Armor(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void attachToPlayer(Player player) {
       // Only equip if upgrade
        if (player.getArmor().res_fire > this.res_fire)
        player.setArmor(this);

    }

}


public class Weapon extends Item {
    private int dmg_fire;

    public Weapon(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    // ...stuff

    @Override
    public void attachToPlayer(Player player) {
        // Only equip this if upgrade? You decide the logic
        if(player.getWeapon().dmg_fire>this.dmg_fire)
            player.setWeapon(this);
    }

}

public class SuperSpecialWeapon extends Weapon {
    private float bonusHealthModifier = 1.0f;
    public SuperSpecialWeapon(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void attachToPlayer(Player player) {
        // This bonus adds +100%HP bonus to the player!
        int hp = (int) ((1 + bonusHealthModifier) * player.getHealth());
        player.setHealth(hp);
        player.setWeapon(this);
    }

}

public class Potion extends Item {
    private int health = 100;

    public Potion() {
        super("HealthPotion");
    }

    @Override
    public void attachToPlayer(Player player) {
        // If the player has room for one more potion, pick this up
        Potion[] potions = player.getHealthPotions();
        for (int i = 0; i < potions.length; i++) {
            if(potions[i]==null){
                potions[i] = this;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // ..other stuff
}
```

And finally the player

```
public class Player {
    private Armor armor;
    private Weapon weapon;
    private String name;
    private Potion[] healthPotions = new Potion[10];
    private int health;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Armor getArmor() {
        return armor;
    }

    public Weapon getWeapon() {
        return weapon;
    }

    public void setWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    public void setArmor(Armor armor) {
        this.armor = armor;
    }

    public void setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public Potion[] getHealthPotions() {
        return healthPotions;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of `Objects_type,` since objects in Java know what type they are, and their type can be tested with the `instanceof` operator. You say that you cannot cast "a mother to its child", but it is possible to downcast an object to a child type. In general, it could throw a `ClassCastException,` but if you have tested it first with `instanceof,` that won't happen.

```
public class Objects_class {
    protected String name;

    public Objects_class(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Armor extends Objects_class {
    int life = 0;
    int res_fire = 0;

    public Armor(String name, int largeur, int hauteur) {
        super(name);
    }
}

public class Weapon extends Objects_class {
    protected int dmg_fire = 0;

    public Weapon(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

public class Hero {
    public void getObject(Objects_class obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Weapon) {
            Weapon weapon = (Weapon) obj;
            wield(weapon);
        }
        if (obj instanceof Armor) {
            Armor armor = (Armor) obj;
            wear(armor);
        }
    }
}
```

I have removed the `abstract` modifier from the classes since there is no need of it, but perhaps you wanted it to ensure that those base classes are never instantiated. Also, I would change the name of `Objects_class` to something like `Item` since the words Object and class have particular meanings that could cause confusion. I would also rename Hero's `getObject` method to something like `pickUpItem` since it isn't a getter, in the Java sense.